# Remove focus on enter key using blur() not working in the Samsung s2

Tags: jquery-mobile

Remove focus on text field when i click enter key.After entering the value to text field and press enter it should no longer focus on same field.

So i used blur() method

```
  $("#Bill_Amount").bind("keypress", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#Bill_Amount").blur();
    }
  });
```

This code is working on chrome,firefox and some devices but not in samsung S2(GT-I9100)

when i click on text field and press done key in samsung,focus is still on the same field.When i click on next field ie datepicker field both are overlapping.

How to resolve this.

Thanks in advance if any help!!

Comment: works fine for me in Chrome (PC, Samsung S4), and Firefox. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7dk82/). Please post some more code (or create a fiddle)

Comment: I used code from the same fiddle its working in Chrome and other devices but its not working in Firefox and Samsung s2

Comment: Does the fiddle itself work on your browsers?

Comment: Now its working but not in the Samsung s2

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `keydown` event along with `event.which` instead:

```
$("#testInp").on("keydown", function(event) {
    console.log("testInp changed");
    if (event.which == 13) {
        $("#testInp").blur();
    }
});
```

Comment: No changes in the issue.If i enter done button in the Samsung its still focusing on same field,but in other device once i click Go button it is not focusing and working fine.